# Request Too Large in apache tomcat 8.5

Tags: xml, tomcat, servlets

I am having the error 'request too large' when submitting a post to the backend. When I add the attribute maxPostSize="4194304" in the connector inside the file `server.xml` the problem goes away. But I don't want to change the `server.xml` file, I want to change the file `web.xml` in WebContent/WEB-INF.

I tried using the following in the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<multipart-config>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
  <max-file-size>209715200</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>209715200</max-request-size>
</multipart-config>
```

But it does not solve the problem.

Can someone tell me how to solve this by altering the web.xml file please?

I am using java servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<multipart-config>` only applies to forms posted as `multipart/form-data`, i.e. you need a form like this in your HTML:

```html
<form action="/your-uri" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
</form>
```

If you don't specify the `enctype` attribute explicitly, then the request is posted using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the connector's `maxPostSize` applies.

**Edit:** If you don't expect Tomcat to parse the `POST` request (i.e. you don't call `HttpServletRequest#getParameter` nor `HttpServletRequest#getPart` or similar), there is actually no limit on the size of the request. E.g. you can test with:

```java
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      try (final InputStream is = req.getInputStream()) {
         final long length = is.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
         try (final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter()) {
            writer.append("Number of bytes read: ");
            writer.println(length);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and then use `curl --request POST --data-binary @<file_name> <servlet_URI>` to send data to the servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to do this. Besides using multipart and connector's maxPostSize, is there any other way to set max post size?

Comment: @JohnR.Daniel: Actually, except for posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` requests, Tomcat does not enforce any limit on the size of the requests. Cf. the edited answer.

Comment: I used multipart/form-data, and I like it more, I think this way I have more flexibility controlling the size of the request with java code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**. When you setting Servlet with `<servlet>` tag in `web.xml`

You can write the configuration code in `<servlet>` tag.

For example :

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.FileUpload</servlet-class>
  <multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>209715200</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>209715200</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
  </multipart-config>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test/files/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Case 2**. When you setting Servlet with `@WebServlet` Annotation

You can use `@MultipartConfig` Annotation on your Servlet Class.

For example :

```java
@MultipartConfig(
  maxFileSize = 209715200,
  maxRequestSize = 209715200,
  fileSizeThreshold = 0
)
```

Comment: I tried this and is not working. It only works when I set maxPostSize in the Connector of the server.xml

Comment: @JohnR.Daniel Could you update your web.xml, Servlet class code?

Comment: @JohnR.Daniel Also, Did you delete XML setting in your server.xml when you use the xml setting in web.xml?

Comment: I updated the web.xml and deleted the setting in server.xml and it's still not working.

Comment: @JohnR.Daniel: are you posting the data as `multipart/form-data`? Otherwise these limits will not apply.

Comment: @Han I am trying now. How do I get the parameters in the servlet? the data has strings and html elements.